# How secure are HTML5 forms?

Tags: html

```
<input id="user_lic" type="number" min="5" max="30" step="5" value ="5"/>
```

Would someone be able to disable this `min="5"` statement and then submit the input with a negative value.

Or for example bypass the type=number statement and enter a symbol

Comment: You should *always* validate user data on the server side

Comment: Any HTML features are only to improve UX, not security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, any HTML can be modified with a basic page inspector. You'll need to include server-side validation to make sure they're not messing with your page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use server side validation.  In addition, I would always use POST for your form, and include client-side javascript validation.